# Unable to send gmail mail

Tags: java, gmail

I am trying to write a java code to send an email via Gmail , I was able to get the correct configuration and code, and have tested my code at home, (email was sent successfully from home), problems appear when I run the same code at work, I was able to figure out the problem is on the network, so I asked my NW admin to open ports 465 and 587 for me and start facing a new issue that I am unable to establish a connection with smtp.gmail.com on both ports , I installed telnet, and run the following command

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
```

and the telnet connection is acting in such a weird way (command shows only underscore (_) and nothing appears, see attached image), note that when I run the same command on any other machine at work it runs fine.

I turned off windows firewall, anti-virus . and still unable to determine what I need to do to get it works since the issue is only my PC.
here is my code:

```
package mail;

private SendMail() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    try {       
        send("mySenderMail@gmail.com", "myPassword", "myRecieverMail@gmail.com", "test java code mail", "this is a text message string");
        System.out.println("Sent Sucessfully");

    }
        catch (AddressException exc) {
        System.out.println("exception"+ exc.getMessage());
        System.out.println("cause:"+ exc.getCause());
    }
    catch(MessagingException exc ){
        System.out.println("exception"+ exc.getMessage());
        System.out.println("cause:"+ exc.getCause());
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
        System.out.println("exception"+ exc.getMessage());
        System.out.println("cause:"+ exc.getCause());
    }
}

public static void send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String title,
        String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException,ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException , IOException {

    SendMail.send(username, password, recipientEmail, "", title, message);
}
public static void send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail,
        String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException , ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, IOException {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

    // Get a Properties object
    String emailHost = username.split("@")[1].toLowerCase() + ".";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
    InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("mail/mailConfig.properties");
    prop.load(stream);

    String smtpHost = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "smtpHost");
    String socketFactoryClass = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "socketFactoryClass");
    String socketFactoryFallback = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "socketFactoryFallback");
    String smtpPort = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "smtpPort");
    String socketFactoryPort = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "socketFactoryPort");
    String auth = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "auth");
    String starttlsEnable = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "starttlsEnable");
    String debug = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "debug");
    String quitwait = prop.getProperty(emailHost + "quitwait");

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    if (smtpHost != null && !smtpHost.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
    if (socketFactoryClass != null && !socketFactoryClass.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", socketFactoryClass);

    if (socketFactoryFallback != null && !socketFactoryFallback.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", socketFactoryFallback);

    if (smtpPort != null && !smtpPort.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);

    if (socketFactoryPort != null && !socketFactoryPort.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", socketFactoryPort);

    if (auth != null && !auth.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", auth);

    if (starttlsEnable != null && !starttlsEnable.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttlsEnable);

    if (debug != null && !debug.isEmpty())
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.debug", debug);


    if (quitwait != null && !quitwait.isEmpty())
        props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", quitwait);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    // -- Create a new message --
    final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    session.setDebug(true);
    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

    if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
    }

    msg.setSubject(title);
    msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");

    t.connect(smtpHost, username, password);
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    t.close();

}
```

and here is my configuration file contents :

```
## ----------------- Gmail -----------------## 
gmail.com.smtpHost = smtp.gmail.com
gmail.com.socketFactoryClass = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
gmail.com.socketFactoryFallback = false
gmail.com.smtpPort = 465
gmail.com.socketFactoryPort = 465
gmail.com.auth = true
gmail.com.starttlsEnable = true
gmail.com.debug = true
gmail.com.quitwait = false
```

[telnet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQvki.png)

btw: I have got the following exception when I run my code

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at mail.SendMail.send(SendMail.java:213)
    at mail.SendMail.send(SendMail.java:111)
    at mail.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:26)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:548)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:207)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
```

I really don't know what I have to do next, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this yet since i'm in an enclosed environment but I suppose what you're trying to do here is keeping the connection as TLS while using port which is used for SSL.

As per the gmail specification, they use port-465 for SSL while port-587 for TLS.

Try either of below:

1. gmail.com.smtpPort = 587

   or
2. gmail.com.starttlsEnable = false

Hope this helps.......:)

Comment: I tried what you suggested , still didn't work , now it says :
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: Brother as I told you, I work in an enclosed environment. I can't troubleshoot it for you right now.
But on a positive note, you are able to connect now but not able to handshake, try altering the configuration file........